# Magento 2: how to check if is category then display block?

Tags: magento-2.1

the magento code below is from magento 1.9...  How do I translate the code below to magento 2.1? I am not familiar with magento 2 api yet.

```
<?php 

 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();

 ?>


<?php if($catalog = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'category'): ?> 

<?php if($category->getId()==503): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('AP_automation_tissue_processors')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==58): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Automated_immunoassay_analyzers')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==379): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Automated_molecular_platforms')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==244): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Bedside_glucose_testing_systems')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==134): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Chemistry_analyzers_for_low-volume_laboratories')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==80): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Chemistry-analyzers_for_mid-and_high-volume')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==208): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Coagulation_analyzers')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==273): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Coagulation_analyzers_point_of_care')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==201): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Hematology_analyzers')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==378): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('In_vitro_blood-gas_analyzers')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==452): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Laboratory_automation_systems_and_workcells')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==460): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Next-generation_sequencing_instruments')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==510): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Anatomic_pathology_computer_systems')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==506): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Billing-accounts_receivable-RCM_systems')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==507): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Blood_bank_information_systems')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==505): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Laboratory-provider_links-software ')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==499): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Middleware_systems')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==493): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Positive-patient-identification_products ')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==508): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Laboratory_information_systems')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==509): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('urinalysis_instrumentation_december_2015')->toHtml() ?>

<?php else: ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('160_600_home')->toHtml() ?>

<?php endif; ?> 

<?php endif; ?>


<?php if($product = Mage::registry('current_product')): ?>

<?php if($category->getId()==503): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('AP_automation_tissue_processors_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==58): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Automated_immunoassay_analyzers_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==379): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Automated_molecular_platforms_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==244): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Bedside_glucose_testing_systems_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==134): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Chemistry_analyzers_for_low-volume_laboratories_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==80): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Chemistry-analyzers_for_mid-and_high-volume_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==208): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Coagulation_analyzers_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==273): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Coagulation_analyzers_point_of_care_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==201): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Hematology_analyzers_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==378): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('In_vitro_blood-gas_analyzers_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==452): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Laboratory_automation_systems_and_workcells_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==460): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Next-generation_sequencing_instruments_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==510): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Anatomic_pathology_computer_systems_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==506): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Billing-accounts_receivable-RCM_systems_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==507): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Blood_bank_information_systems_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==505): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Laboratory-provider_links-software_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==499): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Middleware_systems_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==493): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Positive-patient-identification_products_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==508): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('_Laboratory_information_systems_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($category->getId()==509): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('urinalysis_instrumentation_december_2015_product_page')->toHtml() ?>

<?php else: ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('160_600_home')->toHtml() ?>

<?php endif; ?> 

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

To get the current category

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
```

now you can check condition

```
<?php if($category->getId()==503): ?>
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: will this also work for product page that has the category?

Comment: Yes it will work please try.

Comment: this does not work on search result page, I get blank screen?

Comment: Is it working in other page where you have used ?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your code for magento 2 with the help of following codes.

**Get Current category and current product:**

> Magento 1:

```
<?php 

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory(); //get current category 

$product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId(); //get cureent product id
/*if $this doesn't work for you, you can use below code also */
$product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId(); //get current product id

?>
```

> Magento2:

```
<?php 

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product

?>
```

**Get current controller name:**

> Magento 1:

```
<?php Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName(); ?>
```

> Magento 2:

```
<?php 
/*Same code is used for magento 2, but I prefer you to use $this if you are working in product page or category page*/
$this->getRequest()->getControllerName(); 

?>
```

**Call static block in phtml file:**

> Magento 1:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml() ?>
```

> Magento 2:

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');        --------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                     this does not work on a search result page, any way to get around it?

Comment: Above code is for category pages as you asked for. Search result page is not a category page, that is why it will not work on search result page.

Comment: Will you please explain what you want to do on search result page ?